# How to efficiently make new matrix from sum of blocks from bigger sparse matrix

Tags: python, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a large scipy sparse symmetric matrix which I need to condense by taking the sum of blocks to make a new smaller matrix.

For example, for a 4x4 sparse matrix A I will like to make a 2x2 matrix B in which B[i,j] = sum(A[i:i+2,j:j+2]).

Currently, I just go block by block to recreate the condensed matrix but this is slow. Any ideas on how to optimize this?

**Update:** Here is an example code that works fine, but is slow for a sparse matrix of 50.000x50.000 that I want to condense in a 10.000x10.000:

```
>>> A = (rand(4,4)<0.3)*rand(4,4)
>>> A = scipy.sparse.lil_matrix(A + A.T) # make the matrix symmetric

>>> B = scipy.sparse.lil_matrix((2,2))
>>> for i in range(B.shape[0]):
...     for j in range(B.shape[0]):
...         B[i,j] = A[i:i+2,j:j+2].sum()
```

Comment: Have you tried using numpy's `A[i:i+2,j:j+2].sum()` rather than python's `sum`?

Comment: How do you determine the block size? Is it fixed?

Comment: @wim Actually I am using the sparse matrix sum.

Comment: @NPE The block size is not fixed. Is a divisor of size of the large matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `lil` matrix for the one your are summing up is probably really bad, I would try `COO` or maybe `CSR/CSS` (I don't know which will be better, but `lil` is probably inherently slower for many of these operations, even the slicing might be much slower, though I did not test). (Unless you know that for example `dia` fits perfectly)

Based on `COO` I could imagine doing some tricking around. Since `COO` has `row` and `col` arrays to give the exact positions:

```
matrix = A.tocoo()

new_row = matrix.row // 5
new_col = matrix.col // 5
bin = (matrix.shape[0] // 5) * new_col + new_row
# Now do a little dance because this is sparse,
# and most of the possible bin should not be in new_row/new_col
# also need to group the bins:
unique, bin = np.unique(bin, return_inverse=True)
sum = np.bincount(bin, weights=matrix.data)
new_col = unique // (matrix.shape[0] // 5)
new_row = unique - new_col * (matrix.shape[0] // 5)

result = scipy.sparse.coo_matrix((sum, (new_row, new_col)))
```

(I won't guarantee that I didn't confuse row and column somewhere and this only works for square matrices...)

Comment: Wow, this is a wonderful solution! Thanks! I didn't know about np.bincount

Answer (score 1):

Given a square matrix of size *N* and a split size of *d* (so matrix will be partitioned into *N/d* * *N/d* sub-matrices of size *d*), could you use `numpy.split` a couple times to build a collection of those sub-matrices, sum each of them, and put them back together?

This should be treated more as pseudocode than an efficient implementation, but it expresses my idea:

```
    def chunk(matrix, size):
        row_wise = []
        for hchunk in np.split(matrix, size):
            row_wise.append(np.split(hchunk, size, 1))
        return row_wise

    def sum_chunks(chunks):
        sum_rows = []
        for row in chunks:
            sum_rows.append([np.sum(col) for col in row])
        return np.array(sum_rows)
```

Or more compactly as

```
    def sum_in_place(matrix, size):
        return np.array([[np.sum(vchunk) for vchunk in np.split(hchunk, size, 1)]
                         for hchunk in np.split(matrix, size)])
```

This gives you something like the following:

```
    In [16]: a
    Out[16]: 
    array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
           [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
           [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
           [12, 13, 14, 15]])

    In [17]: chunk.sum_in_place(a, 2)
    Out[17]: 
    array([[10, 18],
           [42, 50]])
```

Comment: FWIW, I timed this with 10000 x 10000 matrices, summing 5 x 5 (so reducing to 2000 by 2000), and ipython says `10 loops, best of 3: 113 ms per loop`. I understand it's considerably smaller than your stated case, but still large enough to be nontrivial--but it's sub-optimal code, too. Can you give some idea of what "fast enough" is?

Answer (score 0):

For a 4x4 example you can do the following:

```
In [43]: a = np.arange(16.).reshape((4, 4))
In [44]: a 
Out[44]: 
array([[  0.,   1.,   2.,   3.],
       [  4.,   5.,   6.,   7.],
       [  8.,   9.,  10.,  11.],
       [ 12.,  13.,  14.,  15.]])
In [45]: u = np.array([a[:2, :2], a[:2, 2:], a[2:,:2], a[2:, 2:]])
In [46]: u
Out[46]: 
array([[[  0.,   1.],
        [  4.,   5.]],

       [[  2.,   3.],
        [  6.,   7.]],

       [[  8.,   9.],
        [ 12.,  13.]],

       [[ 10.,  11.],
        [ 14.,  15.]]])

In [47]: u.sum(1).sum(1).reshape(2, 2)
Out[47]: 
array([[ 10.,  18.],
       [ 42.,  50.]])
```

Using something like [itertools](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) it should be possible to automate and generalise an expression for `u`.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but I think is impractical for a very large matrix. That's why I am using scipy sparse matrices instead.